# JS is not working in WP

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating my WordPress template.
I've included my js files using this code in functions.php

```html
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */

function bs_stylesheets() {

    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-min',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'font-awesome',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'owl-carousel',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/owl.carousel.min.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'owl-theme',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/owl.theme.default.min.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'main',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/main.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_register_style( 'business-school-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), '', null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-min' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-carousel' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-theme' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'business-school-style' );
}

function bs_scripts() {
    //Adds JQuery from Google's CDN. Code pulled from www.http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/
    if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
    function my_jquery_enqueue() {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() ."/js/jquery-2.min.js", false, null);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_register_script( 'owljs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_register_script( 'mainjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs');
    wp_enqueue_script('owljs');
    wp_enqueue_script('mainjs');
 if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
 }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bs_stylesheets' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'bs_scripts' );
```

After that, i can see, that JS is included on my page
[image]

BUT THE PROBLEM is not bootstrap js nor owl js is working.
I can see it because:

1. bootstrap dropdown toggle is not working
2. owl carousel in not working

Do you have any ideas how to make them work? 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: debugging 101: check browser console and network tabs for errors

Comment: @JaromandaX You are everywhere. :-p

Comment: debugging 101: => Step 2 => Clear your browser cache and try again (or) Open your page in "Incognito Mode" in chrome and check :-P

Comment: Can you actually visit the js files in your browser? If you're not getting 404s, are you sure it's accurately retrieving files? Is your htaccess setup correctly? Otherwise it could be that your html or js isn't set up correctly to implement the carousel and toggle functionality

Comment: still nothing works

Comment: Can you show us your markup for the dropdown? Also is jQuery being included?

Comment: @abrosis here is my dropdown http://prntscr.com/e8zqzg . it is working fine in html version without wp. here is jquery including in the head of the document http://prntscr.com/e8zsil

Comment: @Rajesh I have no life :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it will help but sometime dependency might work in WordPress. For this:

```
wp_register_script( 'bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '123', true );
wp_register_script( 'owljs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), '456', true );
wp_register_script( 'mainjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array( 'jquery', 'bootstrapjs', 'owljs' ), '789', true );
```

I have just added the version and the dependency in you main.js. Which means unless the jquery, the bootstrap and owls loads main.js will not load.

If problem still exists, then load the main.js in the header which might be another solution.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Im far from an expert on WordPress, but just because the  tag is part of your html-dom doesnt neccessarily mean that it loads correctly.

If you have FiregBug you can press F12 and doublecheck that the URL is downloaded correctly.

I tried accessing the url: http://bs/wp-content/themes/business-school/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=4.7.2 directly and it complains saying there is no domain called "bs".

Perhaps you're doing something wrong when creating the URL for the scripts?

Comment: Ofcourse `http://bs` is not a domain! it might be a local installation. heard of virtualhost?

Comment: this website is running localy and i have this bs/ domain on my computer. Here what i get trying to access this url: http://prntscr.com/e8zngm

Comment: Again if you have FireBug installed (its an add-on for FireFox) you can actually debug your javascript (put breakpoints and see what is running when you click what etc).

Thats going to be easier if you find a none-min version of the javascript though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your wp-config.php file, hopefully it will throw up some errors to give you a hand!

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true); // Debugging
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true); // JS/Script Debugging
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add links in "header.php".

[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AmSc.png)